# WPF Designer Extensibility: how to get the current designer zoom value?

Tags: visual-studio, wpf-controls, designer

I created a simple custom control with design-time support like the one described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bb907306(v=vs.100))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CustomControlLibrary
{
    public class ButtonWithDesignTime : Button
    {
        public ButtonWithDesignTime()
        {
            // The GetIsInDesignMode check and the following design-time 
            // code are optional and shown only for demonstration.
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                Content = "Design mode active";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to know what is the zoom factor set at design time by Visual Studio, but I cannot figure out how.

[image]

Is there an event that I can listen to for finding out this? Or is there a property that could reveal this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way of doing it, but this is what I came up with. This problem has been thwarting me for ages!

```
    private Point GetScaleFactor()
    {
        var rootVisual = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this)?.RootVisual;
        if (rootVisual != null)
        {
            var transformToRoot = TransformToAncestor(rootVisual);
            if (transformToRoot is Transform t)
            {
                return new Point(t.Value.M11, t.Value.M22);
            }
        }

        return new Point(1, 1);
    }
```

Comment: +1 for your answer! With a custom control derived from System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox it does not work... rootVisual is null :/  ...any ideas?